# Uiimageview changing image causes reposition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I can modify the position of an uiimageview (animating) and it works, but when on completion I change the image of this uiimageview then it goes back to his initial  just before the position change

CODE (working but repositioning the uiimage when I change the image on completion. If I don't change them, it works perfectly and the images stay at the new position).

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
         CGRect frameLeft = singleIMG.frame;
         frameLeft.origin.x-=90;
         singleIMG.frame = frameLeft;
         frameLeft = singleTXT.frame;
         frameLeft.origin.x-=90;
         singleTXT.frame = frameLeft;
         frameLeft = pathIMG.frame;
         frameLeft.origin.x-=90;
         pathIMG.frame = frameLeft;
         frameLeft = pathTXT.frame;
         frameLeft.origin.x-=90;
         pathTXT.frame = frameLeft;

     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
         singleIMG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"singleGRAY.png"];
         pathIMG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pathBLUE.png"];
     }];
```

Comment: This sounds like an auto layout problem. Try turning it off, and see if that fixes the problem. If you want to use auto layout, then you need to position your views using constraints, not by setting frames.

Comment: Uhm but I nuse autolayout for all the other elements.. Can I turn it off just for those images?
Anyway, I think it's not a constraint problem, coz it works perfectly when I don't change the uiimage. But when I change the image, it gets back to his initial position.. wierd..

Comment: No, auto layout is either on or off for the entire storyboard. Changing anything that causes the system to redraw, like changing your image, can cause a re-layout of the view, so I still think this is an auto layout issue.